# Do commoners get money from staying in Bigg Boss?

Tags: bigg-boss

In Indian reality show *Bigg Boss*, in past few years, they give commoners to also participate with celebrities to compete for the winning titles. But it's a common knowledge that celebrity gets money for as long as they stay in the show.

But what about commoners? Do commoners participate for free or they also get any money?

Comment: I'm aware this is irrelevant to the question & even this stack, but the word 'commoner' to describe someone who is not famous bothers me. A commoner is someone who is not royalty [or landed gentry]. Celebrities also are not royalty & therefore also commoners. Having said that, I can't think of a single word to replace it with....

Comment: @Tetsujin that term is coined by show and contestant only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, commoners ARE paid to be on the show, but please note that there is a HUGE difference in their pay as compared to the celebs, celebs take a hefty 700-800k per week (many get 2 million+) whereas commoners get as low as 25k per week.
Commoners are entitled to the main prize basically, which is not at all a concern for the celebs!
All currency units are INR by the way.

My sources inlude the official sites of timesmedia and businesstoday group.

[this](https://www.businesstoday.in/trending/entertainment/bigg-boss-season-12-how-much-money-are-the-contestants-earning/story/282822.html)
[this](https://www.hindustantimes.com/tv/bigg-boss-11-no-payment-for-commoners-this-year/story-EzEMYjRrFrjeWZUaZQq5XO.html)

Comment: 25k per week, get me in \o/